How can I remotely operate a plunger on a large syringe when space is very limited?
I need to depress a plunger on a large thick fluid syringe and ideally it would be remote controlled or able to be activated with the pull of a string.
The problem is the syringe is modified to fit in a confined space and the total operating dimensions can’t exceed 5 inches in length or three inches in diameter.  The plunger only needs to be depressed about an inch or so.
I’ve considered using a micro linear actuator but I don’t know how to control the speed as it only needs to go in one direction then stop.
Because of that I tend to think something spring operated would work best but can’t figure out how to depress a spring that can be triggered with a pull of a string in such a small space.  (The string can be as long as needed)
My only other thought is maybe a solenoid would work but I’m not clear on how they function and if that’s too much force to pull from one
Does anyone have any idea what would be the best way to do this?  I should mention the operating sound needs to be very low to silent as possible.

What about a balloon with increasing air pressure? or diaphragm?

That would work if I could figure out how to fill the balloon. It’s just so compact

Is this single-use application or does it have to be reset - and if so, how?

How much pressure? You may be on to something with the spring as releasing already stored energy can be very compact. For example a spring or foam can be contained by a vacuum, expanding when the vacuum bag gets a hole in it.

I am a cancer patient. I have seen the exact gadget used to pump FDG (Floride 18) into my vain. but I guess that would be an overkill.

Preferably multiple use but not necessarily.  It occurred to me to mimic the functionality of a remote controlled squirting sex toy as it would essentially be doing the same thing I am trying to accomplish in a similar amount of space but I can’t find any blueprints
